# How to prevent datastore auto ids to be negative numbers

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Google announced "In the upcoming Google App Engine 1.8.1 release, the Datastore default auto ID policy in production will switch to scattered IDs to improve performance. "

"These IDs are large, well-distributed integers, but are guaranteed to be small enough to be completely represented as 64-bit floats so they can be stored as Javascript numbers or JSON. "

So, these IDs can be negative numbers? If so, how can it be prevented?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there will be no negative numbers for IDs..

Answer (score 0):

According to [datastore doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Assigning_identifiers) an auto generated ID can be up to 16 digits long.

It's actually a bit imprecise, IDs are the integer part (significand) of a 64-bit floats, so positive integer between 0 and 2^53. Hence the 16 digits long of the doc.

Here is the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/Yt9W204jips/NczERub3Dm0J) where a Google developer confirms this.